# Most number of extra-time Goals

Tags: football, history, records, statistics, trivia

On 30-Oct-2012, [Arsenal defeated Reading](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/20053678) with an incredible score of 7-5. A more astonishing fact is that 4 goals were scored in Extra-time.

Is this the record for the most number of goals in extra-time, in a single game? If not, which match holds the record?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have heard of six being scored in extra time in the FA Cup fixture Leyton Orient v Droylesden, Orient scoring all six in winning 8 - 2.
This took place on 7 December 2010. There is a match report on the BBC: [BBC NEWS](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/fa_cup/9260058.stm)

Comment: That's an incredible match, but I think the question was about goals scored in injury time, not just in overtime.

Comment: @MichaelMyers - The original question and this answer both use the phrase "extra time". Seems like one or both need to clarify the distinction?

Comment: @pjmorse: In the Arsenal-Reading match, 4 goals were scored in injury time and 4 goals were scored in overtime (two of them in injury time), so it could be either. Since Orangecrush accepted this answer, it seems my interpretation was wrong.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know the maximum goals that were scored in extra time, after the game ended in a draw at the end of normal time (90 minutes + injury time).

Comment: Overtime or extra time is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime_(sports)), and is distinct from injury time.

Answer (score 7):

Arsenal and reading 4 goals in overtime isn't a new record.

Most goals scored in extra time in FIFA World cup was **5** goals in the match between [Italy vs West Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italy_v_West_Germany_(1970_FIFA_World_Cup)) on 1970.

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8t1AQZgPgk)

I couldn't find any match with more than 5 goals scored in extra time..

Answer (score 7):

Late reply, but I found a match with 7 goals in extra time:
[DFB Pokal (German Cup)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974%E2%80%9375_DFB-Pokal), 1974-10-26, between Viktoria Köln and TSG Usingen - from 0-0 to 6-1 ([link](http://www.weltfussball.de/spielbericht/dfb-pokal-1974-1975-2-runde-viktoria-koeln-tsg-usingen/), [link](http://www.fussballdaten.de/dfb/1975/runde2/)).

Answer (score 6):

I saw a thread in Tony's Nonleague Matters forum mentioning two more matches with **6 goals** in extra time:

- 2006 Welsh Cup between Queens Park and Brymbo - from 2-2 to 3-7 ([link](http://nonleaguematters.co.uk/forum/gforum.cgi?post=195774#195774))
- [1995 FA Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995%E2%80%9396_FA_Cup) tie between Walsall and Torquay - from 3-3 to 8-4 ([link](http://nonleaguematters.co.uk/forum/gforum.cgi?post=199134#199134))

Answer (score 6):

In **Coupe Gambardella** (*U19 Men's French cup*); [round of 64 and round of 32]

**12 goals** in extra time: Douai SC-Amiens SC: 0-0 to **0-12** [Coupe Gambardella 1998-99](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupe_Gambardella_1998-1999)

**10 goals** in extra time: Besançon RC-Olympique Lyon: 0-0 to **0-10** [Coupe Gambardella 1996-97](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupe_Gambardella_1996-1997)

---

In **Coupe des Dames 2017-18** (*Luxembourg Women's cup*) [round of 32]

**11 goals** in extra time: Union Mertert Wasserbillig-Aspelt Remich Bous Entente: 1-1 to **7-6** [Soccerway](https://int.women.soccerway.com/matches/2017/10/11/luxembourg/cup-women/union-mertert-wasserbillig/entente-aspelt/2593467/)

---

In **UEFA Women's Champions League 2017-18** [Final]

**5 goals** in extra time: VFL Wolfsburg-Olympique Lyon: 0-0 to **1-4** [UEFA](https://fr.uefa.com/womenschampionsleague/season=2018/matches/round=2000912/match=2023928/index.html)

I also saw a match with 7 goals in overtime in the Coupe de France (French Cup) in *round of 512* but I can not find the match in question.

Answer (score 4):

In **German Central Rhine Regional Cup 2020** [quarter-finals]

**6 goals** in extra time: Germania Windeck - Viktoria Arnoldsweiler 0:0 to **0:6** [kicker](https://www.kicker.de/770788/artikel/alemannia_aachen_setzt_sich_in_hennef_durch_arnoldsweiler_schiesst_sechs_tore_in_der_verlaengerung)