# Which team have scored most injury-time(after 90 minute mark) goals in history of La Liga, Serie A and Bundesliga?

Tags: football, trivia, la-liga, serie-a, bundesliga

I know that Arsenal have scored 100 times (highest) in second half injury time in *Premier League* history. But I'm interested to know which are the other teams that have scored most injury-time goals in history of *La Liga*, *Serie A* and *Bundesliga*.

I have tried google but couldn't come up with any article regarding this. The only thing I have found so far is, in Bundesliga there have been 617 injury time goals so far, but I couldn't find team distribution of goals.

And [in 2016-17 season, over 50 injury time](http://www.espn.in/football/blog/tactics-and-analysis/67/post/3170967/why-premier-league-has-more-stoppage-time-goals-than-other-top-leagues) goals were scored in all these leagues.

Comment: Related and also interesting: [Most number of extra-time Goals](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/1784/11439)